# Converting a string value into number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a column with values such as 4w4d, 1w0d, 2w5d, 0w6d.

How could I use this data to get the number of days out?

```
Create Table #temp
(
   Data char(4),
   ExpectedResult int
)
insert into #temp
(
    Data,
    ExpectedResult
)
select '4w4d','32'
union all
select '1w0d','7'
union all
select '2w5d','19'
union all
select '0w6d','6'
union all
select '0w5d','5'
union all
select '0w1d','1'
union all
select '0w3d','3'
union all
select '1w6d','13'
```

Comment: Could you ever have more than 9 weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse out the week component and the day component and then convert into the number of days. The following is one way to do this:

```
-- Find the weeks, multiple by 7
convert(int, substring([Data], 1, charindex('w',[Data])-1))*7
-- Find the days and add on
+ convert(int, substring([Data], charindex('w',[Data])+1, charindex('d',[Data])-charindex('w',[Data])-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string using string operations:

```
select convert(int, left(data, 1)) * 7 + convert(int, substring(data, 3, 1))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40238714ef565c1ba190afea4a7ab2fb) is a db<>fiddle with your sample data.

Comment: Thats assuming only a single digit for week or day.

Comment: @DaleBurrell . . . The column is declared `char(4)` so that seems like a really reasonable assumption.  There are no examples without both `'w'` and `'d'`.